# How to delete ruby surrounding block (do/end) in vim

Tags: ruby, vim

How to delete the surround block delimited by do/end in ruby with vim

For example

```
(10..20).map do |i| <CURSOR HERE>
  (1..10).map do |j|
    p j
  end
end
```

I want to do something like `dsb` (delete surround block) and get

```
  (1..10).map do |j|
    p j
  end
```

Comment: There's [this](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-textobj-rubyblock) plugin, but that defines `ir` and `ar` (inner ruby block/around ruby block) which is close but not quite what you were looking for. It is more idiomatic though, I don't know of any way to do an operation on a *surrounding object`

Comment: vim-surround support such thing for html, `dst` delete surround tag, `ds'` delete surround single quotes, there must to be a way to define `do ... end` as a block

Comment: Have a look at [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich/tree/master); it's a more configurable variant of vim-surround that should allow you do define the corresponding mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can make nnormap.

Every end/do pair is on the same indent, so firstly you should find pair indent - in this case, next line for the same indent (Cause your cursor is in `do` line.)

So you can make vimscript function with finding next indent line and delete it.

This is an example of the function. You can customize you want - i.e.) set indent for resting lines.

```
function! DeleteWithSameIndent(inc)
    " Get the cursor current position
    let currentPos = getpos('.')
    let currentLine = currentPos[1]
    let firstLine = currentPos[1]
    let matchIndent = 0
    d

    " Look for a line with the same indent level whithout going out of the buffer
    while !matchIndent && currentLine != line('$') + 1 && currentLine != -1
        let currentLine += a:inc
        let matchIndent = indent(currentLine) == indent('.')
    endwhile

    " If a line is found go to this line
    if (matchIndent)
        let currentPos[1] = currentLine
        call setpos('.', currentPos)
        d
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap di :call DeleteWithSameIndent(1)<CR>
```

Comment: This is cool!!! It deleted the outer `do` line and moved the cursor the outer `end` line. I tested with the same sample from the question. I think the last if is not executing, this is okay because the I can delete the `end` with `dw`.

Comment: I was planing something like (find do/end -> find expression before `do`, delete expression, `do`, `end`, restore cursor), but my _vimscript_ skills aren't that good. Thanks, this brings some ideas!

Comment: @geckos Great! It's glad to hear that. I'm not good for vimscript, so you can customize your own. Happy hacking!